# Reading bitmap of sizes not multiple of 8 results in shift (and wrap) of pixels

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap

I am trying to understand how to input/output/process images, and from mistake to mistake I got to he following:

Bitmap output:

```
void createBMPFile(PBYTE image, BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi)
{
    //DWORD stride = (((bmi.biWidth * bmi.biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3;
    //bmi.biSizeImage = bmi.biHeight * stride;

    BITMAPFILEHEADER    bmf;
    memset(&bmf, 0, sizeof(bmf));

    // Fill BitmapFileHeader
    INT cbHeaderOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    DWORD dwTotalBytes = cbHeaderOffBits + bmi.biSizeImage;        // File size
    bmf.bfType = 0x4d42;     // Signature = 'BM'
    bmf.bfSize = dwTotalBytes;  // Bytes in whole file.
    bmf.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmf.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmf.bfOffBits = cbHeaderOffBits; // Offset to bits in file.

    // Flip the biHeight member so that it denotes top-down bitmap 
    // bmi.biHeight *= -1;  

    DWORD      dwWritten = 0;
    HANDLE     hFile = NULL;

    WCHAR wFileName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("output.bmp");
    hFile = CreateFileW(wFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    // Dump headers first
    if (!WriteFile(hFile, &bmf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwWritten, NULL))
        return;
    if (!WriteFile(hFile, &bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwWritten, NULL))
        return;

    VERBOSE(TEXT("createBMPFile24: imageSize=%d width=%d height=%d \nbitCount=%d image=0x%08x\n"),
        bmi.biSizeImage, bmi.biWidth, bmi.biHeight, bmi.biBitCount, image);

    // Dump the data now
    if (!WriteFile(hFile, image, bmi.biSizeImage, &dwWritten, NULL))
        return;

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Bitmap input:

```
PBYTE inputBMP(LPCWSTR filename, BITMAPINFOHEADER *bmi)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmf;
    memset(&bmf, 0, sizeof(bmf));
    DWORD bytesread = 0;

    HANDLE  file = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);  

    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ERR(TEXT("Error creating file\n"));
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!ReadFile(file, &bmf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &bytesread, NULL))
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!ReadFile(file, bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &bytesread, NULL))
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    LONG width = bmi->biWidth;
    LONG height = abs(bmi->biHeight);

    if (bmi->biCompression != BI_RGB)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (bmi->biBitCount != 24)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    unsigned long size = bmi->biSizeImage - bmf.bfOffBits;
    PBYTE Buffer = new BYTE[size];
    if (SetFilePointer(file, bmf.bfOffBits, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) == 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
    }

    if (!ReadFile(file, Buffer, size, &bytesread, NULL) || bytesread == 0)
    {
        delete[] Buffer;
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }
    CloseHandle(file);

    return Buffer;
}
```

caller - input a bitmap, display its contents, send it back to output

```
int main()
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapInfoHeader;
    memset(&bitmapInfoHeader, 0, sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader));
    PBYTE pSrcBitmap = inputBMP(TEXT("input.bmp"), &bitmapInfoHeader);

    if (!pSrcBitmap)
        return 1;

    createBMPFile(pSrcBitmap, bitmapInfoHeader);

    unsigned int h = abs(bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight);
    unsigned int w = bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth;
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < h; ++y)
    {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
        {
            VERBOSE(TEXT("(%2d %2d %3d %3d %3d) "), x, y,
                pSrcBitmap[3 * (x + y * w)],
                pSrcBitmap[3 * (x + y * w) + 1],
                pSrcBitmap[3 * (x + y * w) + 2]);
        }
        VERBOSE(TEXT("\n"));
    }

    delete[] pSrcBitmap;
    pSrcBitmap = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting very weird info.

To make all easy to see, I used Paint to make a tiny rectangle (black and white, but the image type 24 bpp).

[image]

The output seems to have color...

[image]

But that is not my biggest issue. The display shows uneven info (see x=14,y=5 .

[image]

It looks like there is a shift in my bytes... and I don't understand why, or how to be able to see a entire row on one line. If the image is not a rectangle but some other shape, this results in a weird wrap of the data (bytes from line 1 placed on line 2, shifting more bytes ...)

I suspect it has to do with stride... But I don't understand how, because the images are 24bpp...

Still, I tried to add 1 to this particular bmp (of w=35, h=10)

```
unsigned int w = bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth + 1;
```

And suddenly my list of pixels seems fine (no shift or wrap):

[image]

I don't understand why... or how to make a correction for any size images.

I tried

```
if (w != (w / 4) * 4)   w = (w / 4) * 4 + 1;
```

Didn't work.

I need to be able to loop through image data, and not have it shifted.... can someone please explain the logic of this shift/wrap/bytes not aligned and how I can fix them ?

Comment: The Bitmap file format is a lot more complex than most would assume. I'd always recommend using a prebuilt solution when reading/writing Bitmap files. The [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) is a viable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bitmap scanlines are zero-padded with 0,1,2 or 3 bytes, so that 
scanlinesize % 4 == 0

this is how you (conceptually) read a bitmap (uncompressed, 24bit)

```
// bmi is a BITMAPINFOHEADER 
// bmf is a BITMAPFILEHEADER
// fp is a FILE*
int w = bmi.biWidth;
int h = bmi.biHeight;
int scanlinesize = w*3;
while( scanlinesize%4 ) ++scanlinesize;
for(int y=0;y<h;++y)
{
    fseek( fp, bmf.bfOffBits + scanlinesize*y, SEEK_SET );
    for(int x=0;x<w;++x)
    {
        unsigned char rgb[3];
        fread( rgb, 1, 3, fp );
        // put rgb in the output here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so great... i struggled with this problem so much before I created the test program above... I had no idea about this padding. Thank you so much !

Comment: The documentation for the [BITMAPINFOHEADER structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318229.aspx) provides a slightly more robust solution to calculate the scanline stride: `stride = ((((biWidth * biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3)`, taking the bit depth into account.